# Error connecting a MongoDB database to MATLAB (Unable to load a message catalog 'mongodb:mongodb')

Tags: database, mongodb, matlab, nosql, data-visualization

I have a MongoDB database I have storing a large dataset. I am trying to import my database into MATLAB to perform data visualization, but am getting strange errors that I have not been able to debug in doing so. I have my database running using mongod on localhost on port 27017.
I do have the Database Toolbox add on for MATLAB, and the MongoDB specific one as well.
Following the example of the MATLAB documentation, I created variables:

```
server = "0.0.0.0" (I have also tried putting localhost here)
port = 27017
dbname = "NYPDData"
conn = mongo(server, port, dbname)
```

When I do so, I recieve the error that:

```
Error using error
Unable to load a message catalog 'mongodb:mongodb'. Please check
the file location and format.

Error in mongo (line 389)
              error(message('mongodb:mongodb:DriverError',mongo.extractExceptionMessage(e)));
```

When I try simple running conn = mongo() with any parameters however, it seems to work, and returns:

```
conn = 

  mongo with properties:

               Database: ''
               UserName: ''
                 Server: {}
                   Port: 
        CollectionNames: {}
         TotalDocuments:
```

If you have any insight on how to solve this error, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Type this before calling the mongo function : `registerrealtimecataloglocation('c:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2017b')`

It should return 1 if everything goes well. Don't forget to change the previous line by your number of version (R2017b here) with yours.
And then it should find the message in the catalog.